How can I declare an empty array in bash 3.2 without unbound variable warnings when referencing it?
Bash version:
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin23)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Consider the following script:
#!/bin/bash

set -o nounset

HELLO_ARRAY=()
# HELLO_ARRAY=( hi  hi )
echo "${HELLO_ARRAY[@]}"

With line 6 commented out, I get the output:
./MWE.sh: line 7: HELLO_ARRAY[@]: unbound variable

With line 6 uncommented, I get the output:
hi hi

Is it possible to modify the declaration on line 5 to avoid the unbound variable warning?
I've already tried declare -a HELLO_ARRAY=() but I get the same warning.

This is apparently a bug that has been fixed in later versions. So either upgrade or don't use set -o nounset

Looks like it was fixed in 5.x, I get the same error in 4.2 but not 5.0.

Is that bug referenced somewhere?

I found the linked quesiton when I googled "bash empty array nounset". It has a link to the relevant release note.

https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES?id=3ba697465bc74fab513a26dea700cc82e9f4724e#n878

The awful Bash bugs related to empty arrays with set -o nounset (set -u) were not fixed until version 4.4 (released in 2016).  Prior to that the only safe way to do the array expansion in your echo command was echo ${HELLO_ARRAY[@]+"${HELLO_ARRAY[@]}"}.
